# Converting Index Match to Dynamic VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have an index match equation that I am trying to convert to VBA code:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Comments!$C$2:$C$100,MATCH(C8,Comments!$A$2:$A$100,0)),"COMMENT REQUIRED")
```

This is what I have come up with:

```
DestinationSheet.Cells(DestinationRow, 8).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Comments").Range("$C$2:$C$100"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match((DestinationSheet.Range(DestinationRow, 3)), Sheets("Comments").Range("$A$2:$A$100"), 0), 1)
```

However, I am getting an error. Essentially, the first formula finds a value located in another sheet based on values in the C column.

For the second bit of code, I am trying to look through the same values in the other sheet, but based on the value in column 3 of a row defined as DestinationRow. I am doing this in VBA code because the row numbers of the entries being index matched are unknown, which is why I must use DestinationRow to specify the row, rather than hard-coding the values like in the first formula.

Comment: One good thing with VBA is that you don't have to write everything in one line. You can split it in parts and assign variables, that way it's way easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like VLOOKUP would be less complex:

```
Dim m
With DestinationSheet.Rows(DestinationRow)
    m = Application.VLookup(.Cells(3).Value, Sheets("Comments").Range("$A$2:$C$100"), 3, False)
    .Cells(8).Value = IIf(IsError(m), "COMMENT REQUIRED", m)
End With
```

Note: there are two different ways of using worksheet functions in VBA

This one:

```
Application.Worksheetfunction.VLookup(...)
```

will raise a run-time error if there's no match, which you'd need to trap and handle.

This one:

```
Application.VLookup(...)
```

will *not* raise a run-time error, but instead return an error value which you can test for using `IsError()`